# Can you do interactive macros or recordings in vim?

Tags: vim, macros

I would like to define a vim macro that breaks for user input at certain times, is this possible?

EDIT: Turns out I ment recordings (q), not macros

It is possible to use the input command in a recording, but it's more trouble than it's worth.

I first mapped insert input escape to a key

```
:map <F2> a<C-R>=input('input: ')<CR>
```

then I made this recording in the q register

```
name:
```

and pasted it into a new tab

```
iname: ^[
```

And after the final escape I pressed `<C-V><F2>` making the line:

```
iname ^[^[OQ
```

That I yanked back to the q buffer then used the macro, letting me use the input function.
It works, but terribly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. See the function `input({prompt}, [, {text} [, {completion}] ])`. There is even 
`inputdialog({prompt} [, {text} [, {cancelreturn}]])`, for a dialog popup.

Comment: vim is just awesome! is there ANY question like "can i do xxx in vim" with a no as answer? :)

Comment: input() doesn't seem to be available in macros (not even through `Ctrl-R=input('prompt: ')`) but if you're okay with normal mappings or functions it will do the job nicely.

Comment: @VictorHallberg: Hmm. Just (re)tried. Works for me (Vim 7.3.547). Just in case, what do you mean by _macro_? Not what `:help macro` explains?

Comment: @fork0: How did you do it? `qq i<C-R>=input('>')<CR>test<CR><ESC>q` will insert `test` when played since it was part of the macro :(

Edit: turns out that what I considered macros are called recordings in vim, my bad :)

Comment: @mogelbrod: Ah, I see. No, I just did a mapping (which is what `:help macro` begins with). `q` does not work, indeed. Sadly.

Comment: I was also thinking of recordings (q) as well. Mapings still get the job done, but it's unfortunate that you cannot watch the effect as you create it.

Comment: @moritz first comment. (it's a joke) Well you can't ask "Can I write all the code in my head in vim absolutely correct with just 5 ?" and get an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use `input()` inside a mapping or macro, the remaining characters will be taken as input, which is not what you want. Vim offers the `inputsave()` and `inputrestore()` functions to temporarily suspend reading from the mapping character stream.

Based on mogelbrod's answer, this doesn't work; the `itest` is read in as input:

```
oBEFORE ^R=input('prompt> ')^Mitest
```

But this does:

```
function! Input()
    call inputsave()
    let text = input('prompt> ')
    call inputrestore()
    return text
endfunction
oBEFORE ^R=Input()^Mitest
```

Unfortunately, because `<C-R>` takes an expression, we cannot put the commands inline, but have to define a separate `Input()` function.

Comment: Hi there, I don't think this works any more. The input is still saved on the macro register.

Comment: @LiarokapisAlexandros: Still working here, Vim 8.2.1719, and failing to do so would be a bug in Vim, as `inputsave()` et al. are expressly created for this.

Comment: vim 8.0 here, it's kind of curious, the text entered while input prompts is actually contained in the macro buffer so it appends the text to next repetition's input. I will have to check with mappings too.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be possible. You can trigger `input()` inside a macro, but continuing on afterwards doesn't seem to be possible as any additional input recorded is inserted into the input prompt.

Yank the line into a named register (`"qY`) and run it (`@q`) to try it out.
Note: replace `^R` and `^M` with Ctrl-V Ctrl-R/M (see `:help i_CTRL-V`).

- `oBEFORE ^R=input('prompt> ')` *- works*
- `oBEFORE ^R=input('prompt> ')^Mitest` *- works, but inserts `itest` into the prompt*
- `oBEFORE ^R=input('prompt> ')<CR>test` *- fails*

Comment: I noticed the same thing. It would be nice if this feature was implemented.

Comment: @everett1992: It is, in the form of `inputsave()` and `inputrestore()`; have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have collected information from this and other threads and written this script:

```
function! MacroInterrupt()
    "call inputsave()
    if strlen(reg_recording()) == 0
        if mode() == 'n'
            call inputsave()
            let tmp_col = col('.')
            let tmp_line = line('.')
            let text = input('input:')
            let line = getline('.')
            call setline('.', strpart(line, 0, col('.') - 1) . text . strpart(line, col('.') - 1))
            call cursor(tmp_line, tmp_col + strlen(text))
            call inputrestore()
            return text
        else
            call inputsave()
            let text = input('input:')
            call inputrestore()
            return text
        endif
    else
        echo "Interrupt added to macro"
        call setreg(reg_recording(), getreg(reg_recording()) . "\<F2>")
        "echo getreg("q")
    endif
    "call inputrestore()
endfunction

map <F2> :call MacroInterrupt() <CR>
inoremap <buffer><expr> <F2> MacroInterrupt()
```

I hope this can help especially people attempting the same.