# Is it possible to easily insert a single word in vim

Tags: vim

I often want to insert a single word with vim. Is there a way to insert as many Chars as you want until you type a `<Space>` which then acts as an `<esc>`?
I know that a normal `i` with an `<esc>` doesn't take too long, but I would like to have such a command and the `<esc>` is quiet hard to reach.

Comment: How about doing a find replace?

Comment: I don't know how...

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace

Comment: Get used to `esc`. Perhaps remap it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider the following

- remap <kbd>caps lock</kbd> to <kbd>esc</kbd> or;
- remap <kbd>caps lock</kbd> to <kbd>control</kbd>, and then use
  the alias for <kbd>esc</kbd> which is <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd>.

Otherwise, though this isn't quite what you're looking for, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494953/insert-a-word-in-normal-mode-as-compared-to-executing-a-command-in-insert-mode) for a possible approach, but also read Ingo Karkat's answer there for why it may not be such a great idea to make such mappings.

Comment: I think I will accept it. It seriously isn't that important

Comment: Another common hack is to `inoremap kj <Esc> | cnoremap kj <Esc>`, as `kj` almost never shows up in English text, is just under your fingers on a QWERTY keyboard, and you can just mash it with your middle and index finger.

Answer (score 0):

Please mention the most underrated `<C-c>`

Comment: They often do the same thing, but they are [not equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030164/whats-the-difference-between-ctrlc-and-ctrl). You shouldn't train yourself to use one as a synonym for the other understanding the difference.